# How to remove customer account navigation menu from wishlist item view page

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, dashboard

I am trying to remove `customer account navigation` menu from `wishlist item view` page.

That means customer account navigation menu will display on the dashboard but when I click on toplink **my wishlist** then it will only show wishlist item without navigation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this code after `</default>`

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <remove name="customer_account_navigation"/>
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</wishlist_index_index>
```

Comment: thats great... you are awesome.